# Why doesn't standard antivirus detect commercial keyloggers?

Tags: keyloggers

I installed SSPRO (commercial keylogger) on my computer just for testing.

Then I ran a scan with Eset Smart Security, and it failed to detect it.  I also downloaded some free spyware removal programs and they all failed to detect it.

Why do they fail to detect it?

I was wondering if since SSPRO is sold as a commercial surveillance program it's not treated as spyware? Or is it a flaw with my antivirus?  Do popular antivirus software usually detect commercial keyloggers?

I would think that is very detectable since I can see the process.

Comment: *"since sspro is sold as a commercial surveillance program its not treated as spyware"* Probably, but we can only speculate. Only the vendors know why they do what they do. As a side note, software recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: In my (limited) experience, any given AV vendor may (or may not) recognize (or not recognize) "commercial" keylogger software as (legitimate) (illegitimate) (both states at once) (now) (later) (now & later) (neither now nor later)..  The only thing you can rely upon are the results you receive at a given point in time...

Comment: Upload to VirusTotal to get a wider view. It is possible that it is simply not classified as 'malware'.

Answer (score 3):

There can be a lot of reasons that the AV did not detect the software:

- The code is signed by a reputable company (known good)
- The binary is a known-good in the [NSRL](http://www.nsrl.nist.gov/)
- The software does not match a malicious signature or attempt to make suspicious network connections

For additional confirmation, check the list of AVs at [avcomparitives.org](http://avcomparitives.org) and test another AV solution on the same system and compare results.